# TYPO3: Creating pdf's from the pages which can be marked

Tags: pdf-generation, typo3

This question is specific to docs.typo3.org please.

I'd like to create PDFs from the documentation on docs.typo3.org using the print dialog, because it's sometimes easier to mark all the things to do before you start doing it.

So e.g. I'd like to print out the https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/multishop/Administrator/Typo3BackendSection/Index.html to a PDF. (Yes I know if the developer would set all the necessaryy things a PDF would be generated, but this is not what I am after here)

I'd simply like to do a Ctrl+P to create a PDF with any of the pdf-creators.

Unfortunately this works in most cases for the 'normal' text, but does not for the headings h1, h2, .... 
The headings seem to be included as graphics an can not be marked/highlighted  in the PDF.

I've tried already several pdf-creators, have looked into the html and .css, but can't find anything how to overcome this issue.

Any solution or suggestion appreciated.

Thanks for your effort to respond.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

As far as I could figure out now, is the `font-family: Share;`, where Share is a Web Font as far as I understand it.

**Solution**

Injected a `font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;` and the problem is gone.